# matlab inline function with argument conditions

Tags: matlab, inline

folks,

I am wondering if it is possible to write the following function of r as an inline function in matlab. I tried to include the condition as a separate factor such as *(r>a) and I got NaN due to the division of 1/r^3 when r is 0.

[image: function of r]

Comment: what is the value of `a`?

Comment: a is a positive number, say 1.

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to be an inline function? Or can you simply get rid of the NaNs a posteriori with something like `nu(isnan(nu))=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fould a simple way out. It's basically what Shai and Jigg suggested, i.e. using an extra multiplicative factor of (r>a).

To get rid of NaN, we just need to add eps to the denominator of 1/r3, i.e.

```
 1/(r+eps)^3 *(r>a)
```

Comment: That is indeed a nice way out, but just if `a > 0` because otherwise you introduce a kind of meaningless value, where it should be infinity.

Answer (score 2):

First, you haven't stated what should actually happen if `r = 0`. Mathematically the term gets **infinity**. I assumed you rather want to set it to **zero**. And what should happen for `r = a`? Just another ill-defined case, are you sure your formula is correct?

If you have the Statistics Toolbox you can use [**`nansum`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/nansum.html). If not, I'd say there is no way around to write your own function similar to `nansum`, which can't be done inline.

```
r = -5:1:5;
a = 1; 
R = 42; %// rest of your function

%// not working, or removing of nan afterwards required
X = @( r ) (r>=a).*(a./r).^3*R;

%// inline solution with statistics toolbox
Y = @( r ) arrayfun(@(x) nansum( (x>=a)*(a/x)^3*R ), r);

output =  [X(r)' Y(r)']
```

`nansum` is not vectorized, if you still want to use it for vectors wrap it into arrayfun.

---

The code of `nansum` does exactly what was suggested in the comments (`output(isnan(output))=0`), I'm probably not allowed to copy&paste it here. It filters out all `NaN` and then sums the input. Use `open nansum` to have insight.

---

As pointed out by Jigg, similar functions like `nanmean` would do the trick as well.

Comment: my function is indeed discontinuous, the r==1 case should be with r>1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
chi = 1; %// arbitrary value
a = 1; %// arbitrary value
theta = pi/3; %// arbitrary value
nu = @( r ) (r>a).*( (chi/3).*((a.^3)./(r.^3)).*(3*cos(theta).^2 -1);
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to mine, but the problem is that `0*NaN`=`NaN`.